# Render Nested json objects in React Native

Tags: json, react-native

In my render() method i need to parse nested json objects. See the portion of render and json structure below. 
I access Last Name with {params.name_last}. 
How will i access items under team, like team.name_first

```js
render() {
        let { params } = this.props.navigation.state
        <Text>{params.name_last}</Text>
}
```

```js
[
 {
  "id": 1,
  "name_first": "Name first 1",
  "name_middle": "",
  "name_last": "Name last 1",
  "name_suffix": "",
  "phone": "888-8888",
  "fax": "888-8888",
  "updated_at": "2015-11-02T21:42:42.000Z",
  "team": [
   {
    "id": 16,
    "name_first": "aaa",
    "name_middle": "",
    "name_last": "bbb",
    "name_suffix": ""
   },
   {
    "id": 28,
    "name_first": "aaa",
    "name_middle": "",
    "name_last": "bbb",
    "name_suffix": ""
   },
   {
    "id": 29,
    "name_first": "aaa ",
    "name_middle": "",
    "name_last": "bbb",
    "name_suffix": ""
   }
  ]
 }
 ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `team` is an array, you need to either access a specific entry in the array, or iterate over the entire thing.

To reach a specific property in the nested array entry (assuming you want the object at index `i`):

```
params.team[i].name_first
```

To create an array of first names:

```
params.team.map(x => x.name_first)
```